# Text overflow division without wrapping

Tags: html, css

I have a division that had some text inside it which overflows the division and there is nothing I can do to get it to wrap at the edge of the division even though it does eventually wrap.

```
<div id="3_column">
    <div class="blocks">
        <div class="img">
            <div class="gallery">
                <a href="/link path" title="title">
                    <img border="0" src="/image.jpg" alt="text" title="text" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h4>
                <a href="/link_path">Title</a>
            </h4>
            <div class="number">number 42 characters</div>
            <div class="descr">
                <p>
                    Description
                </p>
            </div>
```

The division that overflows is `"number"`. I've tried putting padding on both sides, I've tried setting the width to 90%. I've tried defining the wrap on only break word would work. It does wrap but it should wrap earlier.

The code is:

```css
.number {
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I'm sure the solution must be really simple if I can't solve it. Can anyone help please?

Comment: When I try your code, everything looks fine. A `div` is a block-level element and will expand to 100% of its parent element's width. In your case, I see no overflow at all. If you add this to your CSS rule, you can see that there is no overflow: `border:1px solid black;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I can see to solving the problem is finding that the person who wrote to content in the number box used a non-breaking space instead of pressing the space bar. 
Without access to the content, is there a way to set the word wrap and seeing a non-breaking space as a standard space?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine. Try `word-wrap: break-word`

```css
.number {
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  line-height: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div id="3_column">
  <div class="blocks">
    <div class="img">
      <div class="gallery">
        <a href="/link path" title="title">
          <img border="0" src="/image.jpg" alt="text" title="text" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4>
                <a href="/link_path">Title</a>
            </h4>
      <div class="number">1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</div>
      <div class="descr">
        <p>
          Description
        </p>
      </div>
```

Comment: Word Wrap break work works but I don't want to break the word, that would look really bad.

Answer (score 0):

You are combining 100% width with a left padding - that adds 10px to the 100%, making it wider than the surrounding container:

```
.number {
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to this CSS rule, this should help - it calculates the 10px padding *within* the 100% width.

Comment: I'm aware of the issue of 100% width being added to 10 pixels but removing the padding doesn't work. Nor does reducing the width.